# How to monitor mysql master - slave replication in windows os and failover in event of failure of master

Tags: mysql, windows-server, failover, master-slave-replication

I have a master and 3 slave all on windows OS.
I need a tool I can use to monitor replication and failover to a slave incase the master is goes down. What tool do you recommend.
I prefer open source if possible

Comment: Primary-Replica is messy to failover.  Look into switching to a Galera cluster.  Or InnoDB Cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Replication Manager is an option. FYI